# Buffereing in the stdout

Tags: c, linux, stdout, output-buffering

I know the the messages to be displayed is buffered in `stdout`. But consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        printf("Buffered, will be flushed");
    }
}
```

I think that the message doesn't display until the newline is reached. But in this case we have that the pack of the messages will be displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buffers aren't infinite in size. If you output more than the buffer's size, it will be flushed automatically, and you'll see a bunch of messages all at once (repeatedly here).

Here's how the C standard describes the various forms of buffering (C11 draft n1570, §7.21.3/3):

> When a stream is *unbuffered*, characters are intended to appear from the source or at the
>   destination as soon as possible. Otherwise characters may be accumulated and
>   transmitted to or from the host environment as a block. When a stream is *fully buffered*,
>   characters are intended to be transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when
>   a buffer is filled. When a stream is *line buffered*, characters are intended to be
>   transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a new-line character is
>   encountered. **Furthermore, characters are intended to be transmitted as a block to the host
>   environment when a buffer is filled**, when input is requested on an unbuffered stream, or
>   when input is requested on a line buffered stream that requires the transmission of
>   characters from the host environment. Support for these characteristics is
>   implementation-defined, and may be affected via the `setbuf` and `setvbuf` functions.

Emphasis added. POSIX has essentially the same definition, which you can browse online in the [Standard I/O Streams](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05) chapter.

Standard output is usually line buffered.